# Oracle - View in Materialized View

Tags: oracle, view, materialized

I am trying to understand how to change query in materialized view.
But I have 1 question in mind which is if I am using a view inside materialized view script, then when I change the view script what will be the impact for the materialized view?
Do I need to drop the MV and recreate it again?

What is the Performance impact on the existing data upon refresh if view changed?

Comment: No. You can change a referenced view without recreating the MV, unless you change any columns. The MV creates a table based on your query. So as long as only the logic changes and not the columns, you can modify referenced views.

Comment: I am planning to change the logic so does the existing data that already stored will modified by itself(refresh data adapt with new logic) or it will just implemented in new data? Because if the old data is refreshed what I scared is it take quite long time.

Answer (score -1):

fist of all i want to know ,why you want to create a view inside your materialized view ..
as i know that both view and materialized view are both the virtual table of an object ,, the main difference is that if your object is droped your normal view become invalid and but in case of your materialized view you can retrieve the data as it is stored or it take your physical memory,, while creating a materialized view oracle will automatically create an internal table which will hold the data of your materialized view.

Comment: -1 a view is a stored query, a materialized view may be based on a table or a view (or indeed, on another materialized view). It makes sense to maintain the principle of DRY, so an MV on a view may very well be a good idea.